# Bootstrap input group and button alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, input, alignment

I want the input group to be aligned to left, as it is, and "Add new" button aligned to right of the row.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-group col-sm-6">        
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by a substring in good's name.."></input>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="filter()">Search</button>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">          
    <button class="btn btn-default text-right" type="button" onclick="addNew()">Add new</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In action: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/07XgE4Ed1D)

As you can see, input group and "Add new" button are stacked vertically, although they're in a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">        
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by a substring in good's name..">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="filter()">Search</button> 
          </span>
        </div>
  </div>  

        <div class="col-lg-6">          
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="addNew()">Add new</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Separete the `col-lg-6` and `input-group` from the div

Bootply : http://www.bootply.com/W8ao9A0a4r

Answer (score 0):

See below. I moved the add new button code right next to your search button. The input is to the left and the add new button is to the right of that. If you want the add new button to hug the right side of the browser, let me know.

```
<div class="actions row">
        <div class="input-group col-sm-6">        
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by a substring in good's name..">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="filter()">Search</button> 

          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">          
          <button class="btn btn-default text-right" type="button" style="float:right; margin-right:-15px;" onclick="addNew()">Add new</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: No, I don't want "Add new" button to be in the input group, I want it to stay all the way to the right in one row with the group.

Comment: Ok, you didn't originally say that. Hold on.

Comment: Ok done. The button is in a separate row, all the way to the right. It floats to the right, and if the input is moved, so is the add new button.

Comment: Probably, there is something with my spelling, but all I want is for the input and buttons to be in one row (at one vertical level), input group (text field and "Search" button) on the left side and "Add new" button on the right side.

Comment: Yeah that's what I gave you in the first example. You might need to draw it out. Right now I think you mean you want it to look like this: 

[=======INPUT======][Search][AddNew]

Is that right?

Comment: [=======INPUT======][Search][=====empty space=====][AddNew]
So, input group (field and button) is glued to the left edge of the row, and "add new"  is glued to the right.